# how to use opencv flann, especially set distance algorithms?

Tags: opencv, knn

I'm using opencv 2.4.4 flann.

and I refer to: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.4/modules/flann/doc/flann_fast_approximate_nearest_neighbor_search.html

to do KNN.

I have a matrix(8000*32) flann_m. There are 8000 data and each with 32 features.

I wrote code like this:

```
    flann::Index flann_index(flann_m, flann::LinearIndexParams());
    flann_index.save("flann_index.fln");

    Mat resps(ROW,K,CV_32F);
    Mat nresps(ROW,K,CV_16S);
    Mat dist(ROW,K,CV_32F);

    flann_index.knnSearch(flann_m,nresps,dist,K,flann::SearchParams(64));
```

And I could get the KNN results in nresps and dist, with nresps the indexes of N neighbors, and dist the distances.

But I don't know how to set different distance algorithm (ChiSquare, Euclidean, etc.) in opencv flann.

I checked flann.cpp, and it seems the set_distance() function is deperecated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I notice few people are familiar with openCV, and there are few documents.
I finally avoid namespace conflict by using opencvflann instead of flann. And after checking the opencv source code, I found "dist.h" is a helpful file to find how to set different KNN distance types.

In my code, I use manhattan distance, referring to dist.h in opencv source code.

```
//// do indexing
    Matrix<float> samplesMatrix((float*)flann_m.data, flann_m.rows, flann_m.cols);
    //Index<cvflann::ChiSquareDistance<float>> flann_index(samplesMatrix, cvflann::LinearIndexParams());
    Index<cvflann::L1<float>> flann_index(samplesMatrix, cvflann::LinearIndexParams());
    flann_index.buildIndex();

    cv::Mat1i ind(flann_m.rows, K);
    CV_Assert(ind.isContinuous());
    cvflann::Matrix<int> nresps((int*) ind.data, ind.rows, ind.cols);
    cvflann::Matrix<float> dist(new float[flann_m.rows*K], flann_m.rows, K);

    flann_index.knnSearch(samplesMatrix,nresps,dist,K,SearchParams(64));
```